# Docker Swarm + Traefik + Moodle Gateway Error

Tags: docker, moodle, traefik

Having major problems getting my moodle installation working behind a traefik container in docker swarm. No matter what I try, I get a bad gateway error (different hosts in the frontend rule). I've read various posts on stack overflow and tutorials but due to the amount of commands and different options available, my head is spinning. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

```
version: '3.7'
services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v1.6.2
    networks:
      - traefik-proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /etc/traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
    labels:
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-proxy
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-http.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.port=8080
      - traefik.enable=true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    command: --api

 mariadb:
    image: bitnami/mariadb:latest
    environment:
     - MARIADB_USER=bn_moodle
     - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_moodle
     - MARIADB_PASSWORD=bitnami
     - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
     - /var/mariadb_data:/bitnami
    networks:
     - database
     - traefik-proxy
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"

  moodle:
    image: bitnami/moodle:latest
    environment:
     - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=bn_moodle
     - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_moodle
     - MOODLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD=bitnami
     - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
     - 8000:80
    volumes:
     - /var/moodle_data:/bitnami
    depends_on:
     - mariadb
    networks:
     - database
     - traefik-proxy
    labels:
     - traefik.enable=true
     - traefik.http.routers.moodle.entrypoints=web
     - traefik.port=80
     - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:one.test.com
     - traefik.docker.network=traefik-proxy
     - traefik.backend=moodle.app

networks:
  database:
    driver: overlay
  traefik-proxy:
    external: true

volumes:
  mariadb_data:
  moodle_data:
```

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/traefik/traefik.toml`?

Answer (score 0):

At least following should be updated:

1. `moodle` uses port `8080`, not `80`. So, it can be a reason.
2. `traefik.enable=false` should be set for `mariadb` and `traefik` services as there is no sense to send a traffic to them
3. `mariadb` should have only `database` network - means isolation from `traefik`
4. make `traefik` more supportive with `command: --providers.docker --api --api.insecure=true --providers.docker.watch true`

Here is a config for Docker Compose that uses `traefik:v2.0`.

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    networks:
      - traefik-proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    command: --providers.docker --api --api.insecure=true --providers.docker.watch true

  mariadb:
    image: bitnami/mariadb:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"
    environment:
     - MARIADB_USER=bn_moodle
     - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_moodle
     - MARIADB_PASSWORD=bitnami
     - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    networks:
     - database

  moodle:
    image: bitnami/moodle:latest
    environment:
     - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=bn_moodle
     - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_moodle
     - MOODLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD=bitnami
     - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
     - 8000:8080
    depends_on:
     - mariadb
    networks:
     - database
     - traefik-proxy
    labels:
     - "traefik.enable=true"
     - "traefik.http.services.moodle.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
     - "traefik.http.routers.moodle.rule=HostRegexp(`{catchall:.*}`)"
     - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-proxy"

networks:
  database:
    driver: bridge
  traefik-proxy:
    external: true
```

Run

```sh
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose logs -f
```

and when log displays lines like

```
moodle_1   | moodle 11:05:41.68 INFO  ==> Running Moodle install script
moodle_1   | moodle 11:08:14.90 INFO  ==> Persisting Moodle installation
moodle_1   | moodle 11:08:21.75 INFO  ==> ** Moodle setup finished! **
moodle_1   | 
moodle_1   | moodle 11:08:21.77 INFO  ==> ** Starting cron **
moodle_1   | moodle 11:08:21.80 INFO  ==> ** Starting Apache **
```

try to open http://localhost.

BTW,  http://localhost:8080 will open Traefik dashboard. It's useful to see what's is managed and how.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tested it and while it works, I'm a little confused - in the moodle section the ports are listed as 8000:8080 - doesn't that mean that it bypasses traefik completely and goes directly to that port when you go to the <website url>:8000?

Comment: @NickSmith `ports` section within yaml file says what ports for each service should be mounter to the host machine. So, `moodle` mounts `8000` and `traefik` mounts `80` and `8080`. So, if you call `<website url>:80`, the request will go through `traefik` to `moodle`. If you call `<website url>:8000`, the request will go to `moodle` directly. So, ideally, you need to remove `ports` section for `moodle` and use `traefik` as an entry point.